# JQueryUI DataTable collection binding issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am trying to figure out, unsuccessfully, how to bind a collection coming from an AJAX call to the DataTable but sadly everytime I get an error saying that the JSON is invalid (but its not!)

I have a returning object called "response" which has a collection called "Recipients" which has an object of type "Recipient" and has a few props:

FirstName
LastName
EmailAddress

i.e: response.Recipients
which gets transformed to data.Recipients in the clientside call (see below)

I am unsure how to get it to bind - any ideas?

this is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRecipients")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: jsonPayload,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success) {
                        $('#tblRecipients').DataTable({
                            "data": data.Recipients,
                            "columns": [{
                                "Firstname": "Firstname",
                                "Lastname": "Lastname",
                                "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress"
                            }]
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.FailureInformation);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('There was a problem obtaining the selected recipient details. Please try again later');
                }
            });
```

Surely it cannot be this difficult?

And yes, the data is correct. I can see 3 items coming back from the call in the Recipients object.

Thanks for any pointers!

**EDIT** - sample json:

```
[{
  "Firstname": "Tim",
  "Lastname": "Hughes",
  "EmailAddress": "th@test.com"
}, {
  "Firstname": "Joe",
  "Lastname": "Bloggs",
  "EmailAddress": "jb@test.com"
}]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON? I think posting it will make it easier for people to find out what is the issue here

Comment: Sure - just posted it!

Comment: Per my answer below, try playing with property names with and without quotes. I feel like JavaScript and its endless libraries are very inconsistent when it comes to dealing with these two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. No one figured it out. And I believe OP wants an answer. The problem is obviously not if you use `""` in

```
"columns": [{
   "Firstname": "Firstname",
   "Lastname": "Lastname",
   "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress"
}]
```

but that you should define `data` in `columns` correct

```
columns: [
    {  data: "Firstname" },
    {  data: "Lastname" },
    {  data: "EmailAddress" }
 ]
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/796/**

Comment: wow. this almost worked! Thanks David :) - what seems to happen is that it only populates the email address in the table? I do see the firstname, lastname data coming back....

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, see edit - forgot to itemize the columns. Now it works.

Comment: Thank you. this definitely worked! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use aoColumns instead of columns

lets consider below example

```
 var test = [ {"Firstname":"Tim","Lastname":"Hughes","EmailAddress":"th@test.com"},{"Firstname":"Joe","Lastname":"Bloggs","EmailAddress":"jb@test.com"} ];
                    $('#tblRecipients').DataTable({
                        "aaData": test,
                        "aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "Firstname" },
    { "mDataProp": "Lastname" },
    { "mDataProp": "EmailAddress" }
]
                    });
```

I have also created JS fiddle please view https://jsfiddle.net/bj3r2bnf/3/

Comment: This also works by replacing `"aaData"` with `data` and `"aoColumns"` with `columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('#tblRecipients').DataTable({
                        "data": data.Recipients,
                        "columns": [{
                            "Firstname": "Firstname",
                            "Lastname": "Lastname",
                            "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress"
                        }]
                    });
```

to this:

```
$('#tblRecipients').DataTable({
                        data: data.Recipients,
                        columns: [{
                            "Firstname": "Firstname",
                            "Lastname": "Lastname",
                            "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress"
                        }]
                    });
```

I'm not sure why, but using `data` and `columns` in place of string property names also works in @mauliksakhare's jsFiddle.

Comment: What on earth is the difference?

Comment: @davidkonrad Beats me, but it does work. I use this convention every time I make call `DataTable()`.

Comment: There is no difference. If `xxx:` works `"xxx":` works too and vice versa. And why should it work in the nested object literal, but not the parent?